# Excel Spreadsheet: Deriving data for a column in one tab from a search of a column in another tab

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I thought this would be a good job for ChatGPT but it spun me in circles.

So say I have an Excel spreadsheet with two tabs. We'll just say Tab #1 and Tab #2.

So I want to take a given value of Column A in Tab #2, then search for that value in Column C in Tab #1, then look at what the value in the adjacent cell in Column A of Tab #1, and then transpose that value into Column B of Tab #2

I assume it would involve =MATCH but I can't figure out the syntax (and apparently ChatGPT can't either).

P.S. Everything in Column C of Tab #1 is unique, as is everything in Column A of Tab #2

Comment: People have some use after all!

Comment: I think that there would be several questions that already look at such a problem, as well as some answers that would explain how to use the index/match functions. It might also make it easier for readers to visualize if you provided some example data and the expected result.

Comment: You'll need more than just `match`. Instead try `xlookup`. In case it wasn't obvious, this would be what you are putting in column B of tab#2.

Comment: I have things ordered by SOURCE in Sheet #1 Column A, but by DESTINATION in Sheet #2:


https://ibb.co/y63X23R


But let's say I swap the DESTINATION (Column C Sheet #1) adjacent to ALPHA FIVE in SOURCE and adjacent to CHARLIE THREE in C.


SOURCE: ALPHA FIVE was initially adjacent to DESTINATION: TWO DELTA.
SOURCE: CHARLIE THREE was initially adjacent to DESTINATION: THREE ALPHA


But if I swap those destinations, I want the change to ripple into Sheet #2, and update its SOURCE column (Column B Sheet #2) to reflect what we changed in Sheet #1:


https://ibb.co/smJb8Qx

Comment: No carriage returns in comments? Makes it pretty yucky.

Try this:

https://pastebin.com/pHR1GwMx

Comment: So I had checked some existing posts. And from what I saw, suspected that XLOOKUP was what I wanted to use. But I just wasn't smart enough to derive the syntax needed just from looking at those examples. TIA!

Comment: BEFORE: https://ibb.co/y63X23R  |  AFTER: https://ibb.co/smJb8Qx